# ''It was up, wasn't down at all.'' in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

in a memorial, one person said **''it was a lovely memorial.''** and the person who beside her tells **"yes, it was up, it wasn't down at all."** does this mean "it was good, nothing bad at all." or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attending a memorial service you expect a downer ( [someone or something depressing, disagreeable, or unsatisfactory](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downer)).  This particular service was upbeat, perhaps a celebration of a life well lived more than a life cut short.

Comment: thanks for your answer.